# Set a String in a Multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I want to put a string in a multidimensional array at a specific position. The string should be written from right to left.

```
public class PutStringInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            char[][] array1 = new char[10][10];
            String test = "Hello";
        char[2] = test;
    }
}
```

I realize that the code does not work that way. In this example I would like the string (in this case "hello") to start with "array1 [2] [0]" and end with "array1 [2] [4]".
It should be filled as follows:

```
array1 [2] [0] = h,
array1 [2] [1] = e,
array1 [2] [2] = l,
array1 [2] [3] = l,
array1 [2] [4] = o
```

It's probably a very simple solution, but I can not get an idea.

Comment: use `charAt(counter)` and a double loop to insert elements one by one. (`counter` will increment from `0` whenever you insert one char in the array)

Comment: You need to loop over the chars of your String and set each char in the array yourself. Alternativly if you don't really care about keeping the array dimensions equal you yould use the String method toCharArray() and assign the return value to char[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to convert your String to char array.

```
char[][] array1 = new char[10][10];
String test = "Hello";
array1[2] = test.toCharArray();
```

**EDIT**

If you want the string "Hello" to start to array1[2][2], you should use [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
System.arraycopy(test.toCharArray(), 0, array1[2], 2, test.toCharArray().length)
```

Just, take care to the array length.

Comment: Is it also possible that the string does not start with "array1 [2] [0]", but with "array1 [2] [2]"?

Comment: Hmm...ok. It works. But Iam looking for a simple way....I want to bring it direktly to this array-position.

Comment: @Syntax6 If you think this simple one-liner isn't a "simple way" you might have wrong ideas of how programming works and what actually is not simple.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to not define the number of columns you need.

```
char[][] arr = new char[10][];
arr[2] = "hello".toCharArray();
arr[7] = "world".toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[2]));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the `String` and put it into the array returned at index `2`. Just like the following snippet does:

```
char[][] array1 = new char[10][10];
String test = "Hello";

char[] array2 = array1[2]; // char[2] changed to array1[2]
for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++){
    if(i >= array2.length){
        break;
    }
    array2[i] = test.charAt(i);
}
```

The if statement is used so that a string longer than the array size just gets cut off.